# hiding s3 path in aws cloudfront url

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to make sure I did not miss anything in the AWS CloudFront documentation or anywhere else ...

I have a (not public) S3 bucket configured as origin in a CloudFront web distribution (i.e. I don't think it matters but I am using signed urls).

Let's say a have a file in a S3 path like 
/someRandomString/someCustomerName/someProductName/somevideo.mp4

So, perhaps the url generated by CloudFront would be something like:

https://my.domain.com/someRandomString/someCustomerName/someProductName/somevideo.mp4?Expires=1512062975&Signature=unqsignature&Key-Pair-Id=keyid

Is there a way to obfuscate the path to actual file on the generated URL. All 3 parts before the filename can change, so I prefer not to use "Origin Path" on Origin Settings to hide the begging of the path. With that approach, I would have to create a lot of origins mapped to the same bucket but different paths. If that's the **only** way, then the limit of 25 origins per distribution would be a problem.

Ideally, I would like to get something like

https://my.domain.com/someRandomObfuscatedPath/somevideo.mp4?Expires=1512062975&Signature=unqsignature&Key-Pair-Id=keyid

Note: I am also using my own domain/CNAME.

Thanks 
Cris

Comment: WHY do you wish to obfuscate it?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, generally speaking - for security reasons. I do not want certain things, patterns to be implied.

Comment: @Cristian Any solution found ?

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to use a lambda function that receives the S3 file's path, copies it into an obfuscated directory (maybe it has a simple mapping from source to origin) and then returns the signed URL of the copied file. This will ensure that only the obfuscated path is visible externally.

Of course, this will (potentially) double the data storage so you need some way to clean up the obfuscated folders. That could be done on a time-based manner, so if each signed URL is expected to expire after 24 hours, you could create folders based on date, and each of the obfuscated directories could be deleted every other day.

Alternatively, you could use a service like tinyurl.com or something similar to create a mapping. It would be much easier, save on storage, etc. The only downside would be that it would not reflect your domain name.

If you have the ability to modify the routing of your domain then this is a non-issue, but I presume that's not an option.

Answer (score -1):

Obfuscation is not a form of security.

If you wish to control which objects users can access, you should use **Pre-Signed URLs** or **Cookies**. This way, you can grant access to private objects via S3 or CloudFront and not worry about people obtaining access to other objects.

See: [Serving Private Content through CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html)

Comment: Thanks John. I am afraid in my case the requirement is to find a way to hide certain information in the S3 path (for security reasons). Like I said, I am using signed urls and the buckets are secured.